# Expectation maximization in R

Tags: r

We have two  coins, with probabilities of heads $\theta_{1}$ and $\theta_{2}$.The following data give us the number of heads that came up after 10 flips and 5 iterations:
 $x1=5,x2=9,x3=8,x4=4,x5=7$.

Consider from the data above that are the results of the first coin with probability $p$, and with probability $1-p$ for the second one. The terminate condition of the EM algorithm after consecutive iterations $(r)$ and $(r+1)$ is: 
$(p^{(r+1)} -p^{(r)})^2 + ( \theta_{1}^{(r+1)} - \theta_{1}^{(r)}  )^2 + 
                                        (\theta_{2}^{(r+1)}-\theta_{2}^{(r)})^2<=10^{(-10)}$

[image: latex2png.com]

---

for example  I can use the code but i want to make it with while loop and to put the tolerance condition

```
EMflipcoin = function(p,n,theta1,theta2,x) {

    likelihood = function(p,x,theta,n){
    p * dbinom(x, n, theta) / (p * dbinom(x,n,theta) + 
                                    (1 - p) * (dbinom(x,n,1-theta)))}

    M = function(p,x,theta,n){pi.est = likelihood(p,x,theta,n)
    mean(pi.est)}

  tol=10^(-10)  
  maxiter=1000
  diff=1
  iter=0
  while(diff>tol & iter<maxiter){
    ## E-step: 
    d1 = likelihood(p=p,x=x,theta=theta1,n=n)
    d2 = likelihood(p=p,x=x,theta=theta2,n=n)
    p1 = likelihood(p=p,x=x,theta=p,n=n)
    ## M-step:
    m1    = M(p,x,theta1,n)
    m2    = M(p,x,theta2,n)
    p.new = M(p,x,p,n)
    ## calculate diff to check convergence 
    diff= (mean(p1)-p.new)^2+(mean(d1)-m1)^2+ (mean(d2)-m2)^2
    d1=m1; d2=m2; 
    iter=iter+1;
    cat("Iter", iter, 
        ", p=", p.new, 
        ": theta1=", m1, 
        ", theta2=",m2,
        ", diff=", diff, "\n")}
}
x=c(8,5,9,4,7)
EMflipcoin(p=0.5,n=10,theta1=0.6,theta2=0.4,x=x)
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it: What exactly is your question?

Comment: how can i make a function for my problem work